# Does Berkeley DB lock entire database when in a writing operation?

Tags: berkeley-db

I'm researching about embedded database.
I know that SQLite has to lock the entire database when it's processing a write operation. Once the operation is finished, the DB automatically releases the lock.

I'm wondering the same thing with Berkeley DB (I read Berkeley documents, but have not found the conclusion).
So my question is simple: Dose Berkeley DB lock the entire database, or only a certain table, when in a writing operation?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, BerkeleyDB does not have to lock the entire database.  While the details of locking vary according to the access method (see here for more information https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs276a/projects/docs/berkeleydb/ref/lock/am_conv.html), BerkeleyDB has locks that apply to just about every structure in the database, like pages and records as well as the whole thing.

Also note that BerkeleyDB is not a relational database, so there's no "table" to lock anyway.

For something like an in-place record update of a record in a properly-configured application using the BTREE access method, it's likely only locking the database page that contains the record.  Occasionally, record insertions or deletions (or updates that change a record's size) result in a structural change to the tree that involve locking one or more index pages "up" from the leaf where the record is.

Comment: Thanks Mike!
Firstly, I used the wrong word "table"; actually I means "page".

Secondly, from your answer, I understand that if a reading and a writing operation occurs at the same time, but in two different pages, then Berkeley will allow them to happen (because it only locks the page which the writing affects). However, if reading and writing occur in one single page, then Berkeley won't.

Is that true? Thanks so much

Comment: @Triho That's true in many cases.  If the records are on the same page, and the write gets in there first, then the read lock will have to wait behind the write.  Ops on different pages won't contend.  A couple notes: You can configure the database with `DB_DIRTY_READ` to permit reads to see uncommited write data.  That's tricky to use, though.  You really have to know your application if you want to do that.  Also, a typical page size is often 4KiB (and the max size is 64KiB).  If your application contends a lot on records on the same small page, it makes sense to change your application!

Comment: Thanks Mike. Great answer :)